# Shared library between UWP and REST api

Tags: json, rest, uwp

I have a REST service that has many commands that can be called to return JSON data. I have a library of the DTO's that I use to build this JSON. I want to reference this library in my UWP app so that I can ensure they decode correctly. However I cannot reference the dll in my UWP app. I tried the backwards approach too, adding a UWP library to my REST service and referencing it in my UWP app, however then I cannot refrence it in the REST API. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move all your DTO's to a class library built using [.Net Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) 1.4

This will allow you to share code between your REST service and UWP app.

Comment: I made my dll's "Portable", which seems to have solved my issue. How is this different, besides being newer?

Comment: .Net Standard is the just the new Portable. Both will work fine in this situation. I don't think Microsoft will work on Portable libraries any more.